# How I can fix terminal and software center on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

When type this command `sudo apt-get update` then showing me error and Ubuntu software center can't access via Internet, How can I fix this error ?

```
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease
Err http://download.opensuse.org ./ InRelease
Err http://nginx.org wheezy InRelease
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://download.opensuse.org ./ Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'download.opensuse.org'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://nginx.org wheezy Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'nginx.org'
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/./InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://nginx.org/packages/debian/dists/wheezy/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/saucy/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/./Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'download.opensuse.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://nginx.org/packages/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'nginx.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a working internet connectivity ?

Comment: yes, but can't work